# C++, creating classes in runtime

Tags: c++

I have a query, I have set of flat files ( say file1, file2 etc) containing column names and native data types. ( how values are stored and can be read in c++ is elementary)
eg. flat file file1 may have data like
col1_name=id, col1_type=integer, col2_name=Name, col2_type=string and so on.

So for each flat file I need to create C++ data structure ( i.e  1 flat file = 1 data structure)  where the member variable name is same name as column name and its data type will be of C++ native data type like int, float, string etc. according to column type in flat file.
from above eg: my flat file 1 should give me below declaration

```
class file1{
  int id;
  string Name;
};
```

Is there a way I can write code in C++, where binary once created will read the flat file and create data structure based on the file ( class  name will be same as flat file name). All the classes created using these flat files will have common functionality of getter and setter member functions.

Do let me know if you have done something similar earlier or have any idea for this.

Comment: Not possible, sorry. You will need to use something like a map of strings (property names) to a variant data type instead.

Comment: You cannot created class definitions at runtime in C++, you can use a scripting language or even c++ to read such flat files and spit out source files and compile them later.

Comment: I've never used [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/any.html). Will that help solve @rocky's problem?

Comment: There's an idea I've been playing with in my head for a while now. Basically you wouldn't fully integrate the class into the software, but you'd have the software create a (mush simpler) new program, compile it, and then proceed to use it simply by running it, it should be doable. I'm not 100% sure though...

Answer (score 9):

No, not easily (see [the](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8790505/594137) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8790481/594137) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8790471/594137) for reasons why not).

I would suggest having a look at [Python](http://python.org/) instead for this kind of problem. [Python's type system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#In_Python) combined with its ethos of using `try`/`except` lends itself more easily to the challenge of parsing data.

If you really must use C++, then you might find a solution using the [dynamic properties](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#dynamic-properties) feature of [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/learning)'s [QObject](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html) class, combined with the [QVariant](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qvariant.html) class.  Although this would do what you want, I would add a **warning** that this is getting kind of heavy-weight and may over-complicate your task.

Comment: @ downvoter, Care to explain why this isn't helpful?  It says quite clearly "Do let me know if you have done something similar earlier or have any idea for this."

Comment: Me too - I am with you -  (+1)

Comment: @Styne666: I have no idea who did it and why, but for me this answer lacks at least some short explanation as to why python is better. As it is now, it sounds a bit like a pet language advertisement.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I do not advocate favourite languages. It is obvious however that some languages do certain things better than others; this being a prime example. I gauged the detail of my answer based on that of the question but, to satisfy you, I have added a few pointers on where one could research next.

Comment: @Styne666: +1 for that. This will also satisfy everyone else that don't know enough python for it being obvious.

Comment: @PlasmaHH is correct; originally this was not an answer to the stated question but a "just use another language" response that's not entirely helpful. But, now that it addresses the specifics of the question, it's great. :)

Answer (score 8):

No, not directly. C++ is a compiled language. The code for every class is created by the compiler.

You would need a two-step process. First, write a program that reads those files and translates them into a .cpp file. Second, pass those .cpp files to a compiler.

Comment: @Seth: That's why the first word of my answer is "No". However, you _could_ compile this code into a DLL and load that dynamically. Is that useful? I can't tell from this question.

Comment: Incredible idea compiling and loading a dll, nice one. This could be an interesting experimental solution in my current project

Answer (score 6):

C++ classes are pure compile-time concepts and have no meaning at runtime, so they cannot be created. However, you could just go with

```
std::vector<std::string> fields;
```

and parse as necessary in your accessor functions.

Comment: `boost::any` might be better than `std::string`.

Answer (score 5):

No, but from what I can tell, you have to be able to store the names of multiple columns. What you can do is have a member variable `map` or `unordered_map` which you can index with a string - the name of the column - and get some data (like a column object or something) back. That way you can do

```
obj.Columns["Name"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a design pattern to this, but if your list of possible type names is finite, and known at compile time, can't you declare all those classes in your program before running, and then just instantiate them based on the data in the files?

Comment: All, thanks for replying to my query and helping me out. Also, my main concern is to implement single binary and ship it to different clients. The flat file structure given by clients will be different, so this binary should be generic that can handle the data structures on fly. Ofcourse the the main functionality of the binary is similar to all clients, except we need to cater to different data client is giving us, hence this all mess. I hope am making my point clear. I thought this may be possible using meta programming or reflections in C++. but i am quiet new to those concepts.

Comment: I think You should just view those text files as input to be parsed. Personally, I'd use unions for storing the data. But of course, you must know beforehand what to expect in the text files and think up structures than can contain all the different data, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want is a field whose exact nature varies at runtime.

There are several approaches, including `Boost.Any`, but because of the static nature of C++ type system only 2 are really recommended, and both require to have beforehand an idea of all the possible data types that may be required.

The first approach is typical:

- `Object` base type
- `Int`, `String`, `Date` whatever derived types

and the use of polymorphism.

The second requires a bit of Boost magic: `boost::variant<int, std::string, date>`.

Once you have the "variant" part covered, you need to implement visitation to distinguish between the different possible types. Typical visitors for the traditional object-oriented approach or simply `boost::static_visitor<>` and `boost::apply_visitor` combinations for the boost approach.

It's fairly straightforward.